# Proof that polynome $P(x)$ is divisible by $Q(x)$

Tags: polynomials, solution-verification

> Prove that the polynome 
>   $$P(x)=nx^{n+1}-(1+n\lambda)x^n+(\lambda-1)(x^{n-1}+...+x)+\lambda$$
>   is divisible by:
>   $$Q(x)=x^2-(\lambda+1)x+\lambda$$
>   where $\lambda\in\Bbb{C}$

So first I found the roots of $Q(x)$, assuming if $P$ is divisible by $Q$, the remainder must be $0$.

$$x^2-(\lambda+1)x+\lambda=0\iff x_{1/2}={\lambda+1\pm\sqrt{(\lambda+1)^2-4\lambda}\over2}$$

from here, since $\lambda\in\Bbb{C}$, I can say:

$x_1=\lambda\\x_2=1$

now I thought I should find $P(\lambda)$. After a long simplification I got that:

$$P(\lambda)=\lambda^{n+2}-2\lambda^{n+1}-\lambda^3+2\lambda^2$$

at this point I'm lost. This would equal to zero if $\lambda=0$ but that doesn't prove me anything.

Comment: So you see that the roots are $\lambda$ and $1$. Now substitute those values for $x$ into $P(x)$. If both are roots, you are done.

Comment: Oh so probably I made a mistake while calculating $P(\lambda)$, I'll try again!

Comment: If $\lambda =1$, then it doesn't follow that $(x-\lambda)(x-1)$ divides $p(x)$. In this case you need to show that $1$ is a double root of $p(x)$. You can do that by checking $p'(1)=0$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alternatively, it is easy to check that $$P(x)=Q(x)(nx^{n-1}+(n-1)x^{n-2}+\dots+3z^2+2x+1)$$ That still works for $\lambda=1$ whereas the approach of checking that $1,\lambda$ are roots of $P(x)$ requires a continuity argument (or checking the derivative) for $\lambda=1$.

Answer (score 1):

You have found the roots.

It is straightforward to see that
\begin{align*}
P(1) =& n-(1+n \lambda) + (\lambda -1)(n-1) + \lambda \\
=& n-1-n \lambda + n\lambda-n-\lambda+1+\lambda \\
=& 0\\
\\
P(\lambda) =& n \lambda^{n+1} - (1+n\lambda)\lambda^n + (\lambda-1)(\lambda^{n-1} + \ldots + \lambda) + \lambda \\
=& n\lambda^{n+1} - \lambda^n-n\lambda^{n+1}+\lambda^n-\lambda+\lambda \\
=& 0
\end{align*}
Hence, both $x-1$ and $x-\lambda$ are divisors of $P$, which means $Q(x) = (x-1)(x-\lambda)$ must also be one.

Comment: Your conclusion isn't true if f $\lambda= 1$.

Comment: Oh I see I messed up in my calculation for $P(\lambda)$, could you just shortly explain what you did with $(\lambda^{n-1}+...+\lambda)$ as that is the part I probably messed up